# Binding visibility to a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a dependency property allowing me to show or hide the close button on my `UserControl`.  I get no compile errors but the close button never disappears with the following code, what am I missing?

Calling using:

```
<Toolkit:UC_TitleBar ShowCloseButton="False"/>
```

.cs code

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCloseButtonProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCloseButton", 
    typeof(Boolean), 
    typeof(UC_TitleBar), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

public bool ShowCloseButton
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowCloseButtonProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShowCloseButtonProperty, value); }
}
```

XAML inside UserControl:

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="ucTitleBar">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowCloseButton, ElementName=ucTitleBar, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" x:Name="Button_Close"/>
```

If I manually set `ShowCloseButton` to false in the constructor it disappears as you'd expect.

Comment: Does it really need to be a two-way binding?

Comment: No, I'm just trying various bits to get it working. It only needs to read the `ShowCloseButton` attribute off the calling XAML in `<Toolkit:UC_TitleBar ShowCloseButton="False"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have to use element name binding like below.

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=userControl1,Path=ShowCloseButton, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" x:Name="Button_Close"/>
```

if this not works for you please share your code with us.

Comment: share the All relevant code where you are using the button for visibility.

Comment: All the visibility code is done using the built in `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` converter